# #1111 - Invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, mariasql

The following query is failing and complaining about  `#1111 - Invalid use of group function` because of the both SUM() calls embedded inside the IF loops. By now i'm trying to accomplish the same goals while migrating to another SQL query but i'm having osme hard time, could any one point me to the right direction?

Database is composed by an `invoices` table which may have some `invoices_payments` if the client hasn't paid the invoice at once and instead have gone by instal payments. Known that, i'm trying to sum up all invoices.invoice_total substracting each invoices_payments.payment_date whichs not equals the current week only if invoices.issued_date equals the current week, if not then i'm trying to sum all invoices_payments.payment_amount where invoices_payments.payment_date equals the current week.

```
SELECT
    SUM(

        IF (
            YEARWEEK(i.issue_date, 1) = YEARWEEK(NOW(), 1),
            i.invoice_total,
            0
        )
    ) AS week_invoiced,
    ##SUM Functions embedded inside the next IF are causing error: #1111 - Invalid use of group function
    SUM(

        IF (
            ## If payment is issued on current week
            i.issued_date IS NOT NULL
            AND YEARWEEK(i.issued_date, '%Y%m') = YEARWEEK(NOW(), '%Y%m'),
            ## Sum each invoice.invoice_total and substract each invoices_payments not issued on current week
            SUM(i.invoice_total) - SUM(

                IF (
                    ip.id IS NOT NULL
                    AND YEARWEEK(ip.payment_date, 1) != YEARWEEK(NOW(), 1),
                    ip.payment_amount,
                    0
                )
            ),

        IF (
            ## If payment is not issued on current week
            i.issued_date IS NULL
            OR (
                i.issued_date IS NOT NULL
                AND YEARWEEK(i.issued_date, '%Y%m') != YEARWEEK(NOW(), '%Y%m')
            ),
            ## Sum each invoices_payments issued on current week
            SUM(

                IF (
                    ip.id IS NOT NULL
                    AND YEARWEEK(ip.payment_date, 1) = YEARWEEK(NOW(), 1),
                    ip.payment_amount,
                    0
                )
            ),
            0
        )
        )
    ) AS week_paid,
    SUM(

        IF (
            DATE_FORMAT(i.issue_date, '%Y%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m'),
            i.invoice_total,
            0
        )
    ) AS month_invoiced
FROM
    `invoices` AS i
INNER JOIN `currency` AS cur ON i.currency_id = cur.id
LEFT JOIN `invoices_payments` AS ip ON ip.invoice_id = i.id
WHERE
    i.coach_id = 279
AND (
    DATE_FORMAT(i.issue_date, '%Y%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m')
    OR DATE_FORMAT(i.issued_date, '%Y%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m')
    OR (
        ip.id IS NOT NULL
        AND DATE_FORMAT(ip.payment_date, '%Y%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m')
    )
)
GROUP BY
    i.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the outer `SUM` where the problem is.  That is, the inner SUMs suffice:

```
SUM( SUM()-SUM() )
```

-->

```
SUM()-SUM()
```